# How can I get part of url in Cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, ui-automation

Im generating ids and then using id to `cy.visit` them , I wanna assert the generated id using `cy.url().split('/')` but I can not , Split works only for strings and `cy.url()` returns `Chainable<string>` , any other ways to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. Swap out 0 for whatever index you need.

```
cy.url().then(url => {
  cy.log(url.split('/')[0])
});
```

Comment: Thanks , .then() was the answer , I tried to avoid it but in this case it’s the only answer thanks anyways!